# Changing AppBarButton Icon

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, winrt-xaml

In my Windows 10 universal application I've Got a AppBarButton in a page:

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="PinBtn" Icon="Pin" Click="PinBtn_Click"/>
```

I want to check if `Icon="Pin"` then UnPin it and vice versa.

So I tried to code like this:

```
  private void PinBtn_Click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(PinBtn.Icon == new SymbolIcon((Symbol.Pin)))
        {
            PinBtn.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.UnPin);
        }
        else {
            PinBtn.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Pin);
        }
    }
```

Problem : `(PinBtn.Icon == new SymbolIcon((Symbol.UnPin)))` always return **FALSE**

What's the problem and fix for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not going to work 'cause `Icon` is a reference type. It will never be equal to a new instance of `SymbolIcon`.

You should be using a `AppBarToggleButton` in this case instead and subscribe to the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events.

```
<AppBarToggleButton x:Name="PinToggle" Icon="Pin" Checked="PinToggle_Checked" Unchecked="PinToggle_Unchecked" />

private void PinToggle_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PinToggle.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.UnPin);
}

private void PinToggle_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PinToggle.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Pin);
}
```